# MATLAB beginning having difficulty with function handles

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I'm working on a project for school that basically involves iteratively solving a cubic equation. I'm using MATLAB for it, but I've never really done much with MATLAB so I'm having some trouble with the logic of it.

Here's my code:

```
% Redlich/Kwong EOS
sigma = 1;
epsilon = 0;
omega = 0.08664;
psi = 0.42748;

beta = @(Psat_RK) omega*PsatRK/Pc/Tr(1); % Pc is in bar, may need a unit conversion later
alpha = (Tr(1))^(-1/2);
q = psi*alpha/omega/Tr(1);

A = @(beta) (sigma + epsilon - 1)*beta - 1;
B = @(beta) (sigma*epsilon - sigma - epsilon)*(beta^2) + (q - sigma - epsilon)*beta;
C = @(beta) -(sigma*epsilon*(1+beta) + q)*(beta^2);

Q = @(A,B)   ((A^2) - 3*B)/9;
R = @(A,B,C) (2*(A^3) - 9*A*B + 27*C)/54;
M = @(R,Q)   R^2 - Q^3;

if M > 0
    Z_single = ((-R+(M^0.5))^(1/3)) + ((-R-(M^0.5))^(1/3)) - (A/3);

    I = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_single+sigma*beta)/(Z_single+epsilon*beta));
end

if M < 0
   theta = acos(R/(Q^(1/3)));
   Z(1) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos(theta/3)) - (A/3);
   Z(2) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta + 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);
   Z(3) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta - 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);

   Z_liquid = min(Z)
   Z_vapor = max(Z)

   I_liquid = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_liquid+sigma*beta)/(Z_liquid+epsilon*beta));
   I_vapor = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_vapor+sigma*beta)/(Z_vapor+epsilon*beta));
end

ln_phi_liquid = Z_liquid - 1 - log(Z_liquid - beta) - q*I_liquid;
ln_phi_vapor = Z_vapor - 1 - log(Z_vapor - beta) - q*I_vapor;

objfun = (ln_phi_liquid - ln_phi_vapor);

Psat_RK_solved = fsolve(objfun,10);
```

Basically, I'm trying to iterate on the value of `Psat_RK` until the `objfun` equals 0. I can post more details of the math if needed, but I figured this would be enough to get started. Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to actually mention the problem.

Here's the error I'm getting.

> Undefined operator '>' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
>
> Error in Proj2 (line 73)
>   if M > 0

I can't figure out how to establish in this line that M is being calculated off an anonymous function.

---

EDIT:

```
sigma = 1;
epsilon = 0;
omega = 0.08664;
psi = 0.42748;

beta = @(Psat_RK) omega*PsatRK/Pc/Tr(1); % Pc is in bar, may need a unit conversion later
alpha = (Tr(1))^(-1/2);
q = psi*alpha/omega/Tr(1);

A = @(Psat_RK) (sigma + epsilon - 1)*beta(Psat_RK) - 1;
B = @(Psat_RK) (sigma*epsilon - sigma - epsilon)*(beta(Psat_RK)^2) + (q - sigma - epsilon)*beta(Psat_RK);
C = @(Psat_RK) -(sigma*epsilon*(1+beta(Psat_RK)) + q)*(beta(Psat_RK)^2);

Q = @(Psat_RK) ((A(Psat_RK)^2) - 3*B(Psat_RK))/9;
R = @(Psat_RK) (2*(A(Psat_RK)^3) - 9*A(Psat_RK)*B(Psat_RK) + 27*C(Psat_RK))/54;
M = @(Psat_RK) R(Psat_RK)^2 - Q(Psat_RK)^3;

if M(Psat_RK) > 0
    Z_single = ((-R+(M^0.5))^(1/3)) + ((-R-(M^0.5))^(1/3)) - (A/3);

    I = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_single+sigma*beta)/(Z_single+epsilon*beta));
end

if M(Psat_RK) < 0
   theta = acos(R/(Q^(1/3)));
   Z(1) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos(theta/3)) - (A/3);
   Z(2) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta + 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);
   Z(3) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta - 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);

   Z_liquid = min(Z)
   Z_vapor = max(Z)

   I_liquid = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_liquid+sigma*beta)/(Z_liquid+epsilon*beta));
   I_vapor = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_vapor+sigma*beta)/(Z_vapor+epsilon*beta));
end

ln_phi_liquid = Z_liquid - 1 - log(Z_liquid - beta) - q*I_liquid;
ln_phi_vapor = Z_vapor - 1 - log(Z_vapor - beta) - q*I_vapor;

objfun = (ln_phi_liquid - ln_phi_vapor);

Psat_RK_solved = fsolve(objfun,10);
```

I know the code needs some work further down, but the code below shouldn't affect why it hangs at the first `if` statement, right? The error is:

Undefined function or variable 'Psat_RK'.

Error in Proj2 (line 122)
if M(Psat_RK) > 0

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to add the error. Edited to fix.

Comment: The errors are both clearly explicit. You have defined `M` as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). A function cannot be logically compared to a number, it makes no sense computationally. You receive the second error because you have not defined `Psat_RK`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) incorrectly.

If we take a look at one of them:

```
Q = @(A,B)   ((A^2) - 3*B)/9;
```

To MATLAB, this is the equivalent of this function:

```
function C = Q(A, B)
    C = ((A^2) - 3*B) / 9;
end
```

`Q` is the *name* of the function and doesn't represent a *value*. If, however, you pass `Q` the two arguments that it needs (`A` and `B`), then it will yield a value.

Obviously, you would want to call this in the following way:

```
value = Q(a,b);
```

If you look at your own code, you try to use `Q` *directly* as if it were a value rather than a function handle.

```
Z(1) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos(theta/3)) - (A/3);
```

If we break down this single line a little more, we realize that `A` (one of the inputs to `Q`) is *also* an anonymous function. Same actually goes for `B`.

Then further down the rabbit hole, `A` and `B` depend upon the output of the anonymous function `beta` which is *finally* defined at the top.

```
beta = @(Psat_RK) omega*PsatRK/Pc/Tr(1);
```

So assuming we have a value for `Psat_RK`, this whole chain would look like this.

```
betaValue = beta(Psat_RK);

aValue = A(betaValue);
bValue = B(betaValue);

qValue = A(aValue, bValue);
```

Now you can use `qValue` as a *value* and the statement above would become

```
Z(1) = -2 * (qValue ^ 0.5) * (cos(theta / 3)) - (aValue / 3);
```

If you wanted to simplify this, you *could* redefine `Q` to be:

```
Q = @(Psat_RK)(A(beta(Psat_RK))^2 - 3 * B(beta(Psat_RK))) / 9;
```

This applies to *all* anonymous functions you have defined (including `M` which is giving you your first error).

### Summary

Anonymous functions are useful for a number of things and [functional programmers love them](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/). For your case, I would *probably* recommend that you just write a simple function that is a function of `Psat_RK` and create a *single* anonymous function for that and pass it to `fsolve`.

```
fsolve(@objectiveFUnction, x0);

function value = objectiveFunction(Psat_RK)
    % Do all your calculations here to get objfun given Psat_RK
    % No anonymous functions needed here!
end
```

### Addendum

If we wanted to convert all of your anonymous functions to be a function of `Psat_RK` they would look like this.

```
A = @(Psat_RK) (sigma + epsilon - 1) * beta(Psat_RK) - 1;
B = @(Psat_RK) (sigma * epsilon - sigma - epsilon)*(beta(Psat_RK)^2) + (q - sigma - epsilon)*beta(Psat_RK);
C = @(Psat_RK) -(sigma*epsilon*(1+beta(Psat_RK)) + q)*(beta(Psat_RK)^2);

Q = @(Psat_RK) ((A(Psat_RK)^2) - 3*B(Psat_RK))/9;
R = @(Psat_RK) (2*(A(Psat_RK)^3) - 9*A(Psat_RK)*B(Psat_RK) + 27*C(Psat_RK))/54;
M = @(Psat_RK) R(Psat_RK)^2 - Q(Psat_RK)^3;
```

### Example

Here is how I would write this as a separate function without all of those anonymous functions.

**objectiveFunction.m**

```
function value = objectiveFunction(psat)

    % Redlich/Kwong EOS
    sigma = 1;
    epsilon = 0;
    omega = 0.08664;
    psi = 0.42748;

    % Pc is in bar, may need a unit conversion later
    beta = omega * psat / Pc / Tr(1);  % NOT SURE WHAT Tr or Pc ARE
    alpha = (Tr(1))^(-1/2);
    q = psi*alpha/omega/Tr(1);

    A = (sigma + epsilon - 1)*beta - 1;
    B = (sigma*epsilon - sigma - epsilon)*(beta^2) + (q - sigma - epsilon)*beta;
    C = beta -(sigma*epsilon*(1+beta) + q)*(beta^2);

    Q = ((A^2) - 3*B)/9;
    R = (2*(A^3) - 9*A*B + 27*C)/54;
    M = R^2 - Q^3;

    if M > 0
        Z_single = ((-R+(M^0.5))^(1/3)) + ((-R-(M^0.5))^(1/3)) - (A/3);

        I = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_single+sigma*beta)/(Z_single+epsilon*beta));
    end

    if M < 0
        theta = acos(R/(Q^(1/3)));
        Z(1) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos(theta/3)) - (A/3);
        Z(2) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta + 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);
        Z(3) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta - 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);

        Z_liquid = min(Z);
        Z_vapor = max(Z);

        I_liquid = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_liquid+sigma*beta)/(Z_liquid+epsilon*beta));
        I_vapor = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_vapor+sigma*beta)/(Z_vapor+epsilon*beta));
    end

    ln_phi_liquid = Z_liquid - 1 - log(Z_liquid - beta) - q*I_liquid;
    ln_phi_vapor = Z_vapor - 1 - log(Z_vapor - beta) - q*I_vapor;

    value = (ln_phi_liquid - ln_phi_vapor);
end
```

Then from the MATLAB command window, you could type the following to get your solution.

```
Psat_RK_solved = fsolve(@objectiveFunction, 10);
```

This way, the *only* anonymous function is the one that you use to point `fsolve` to your actual objective function.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I'm still a little confused. Like I mentioned above, I'm trying to iterate on the value of Psat_RK to solve an objective function, so will this work with Psat_RK changing constantly (via fsolve, presumably)?

Comment: @jbf I have added a summary to bring this back to your problem. I recommend that you rewrite all of the anonymous functions into normal functions and then pass them to `fsolve` as demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try to rewrite it like you've suggested but I still am not really clear on how exactly it works. I'll edit the main post with the new code if I still can't make it work.

Comment: @jbf How it's written is really confusing. If you look at my addendum I've broken it down so that all anonymous functions are a function of `Psat_RK`. You would then do your comparison like `if M(Psat_RK) > 0`

Comment: The addendum make more sense to me - that's more like what I was trying to do. I edited my code to try it but it still gives me an error at the first `if` statement: "Undefined function or variable 'Psat_RK'.
Error in Proj2 (line 122)
if M(Psat_RK) > 0" -- I edited the original question to my new code.

Comment: @jbf I just added a full  example. `Psat_RK` is a value that `fsolve` should pass to your function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106168/discussion-between-jbf-and-suever).